# What is the lingustic term for a language's usage conventions?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

Every language has usage conventions that cannot be deducted from a basic dictionary. For example, to describe highly concentrated tea, English speakers will usually use "strong tea". Is there a scientific/linguistic term for such conventions/word pairings?

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is **collocation**:

> In corpus linguistics, a collocation is a sequence of words or terms that co-occur more often than would be expected by chance. In phraseology, collocation is a sub-type of phraseme. An example of a phraseological collocation, as propounded by Michael Halliday, is the expression *strong tea*.
> <sub>[Wikipedia: Collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)</sub>

The right dictionary to use in this case is a collocation dictionary, such as [OZDIC](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/tea). Alternatively, several Ngram tools can be used for this: searching `*_ADJ tea` in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+tea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgreen_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhot_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bblack_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blittle_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstrong_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bweak_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmore_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Biced_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgood_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsilver_ADJ%20tea%3B%2Cc0) or `_j* tea` in a [BYU corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/) will tell you which adjectives are used before tea.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. It seems to be related to statistical NLP. I was looking for something a little different: say I am looking for an ADJECTIVE to describe a NOUN. I am looking for a term that describes conventional ADJECTIVES that can be used for the NOUN... not sure if that makes sense :-)

Comment: @Sleepster It's still a collocation. See edit for more info.